# Arithmetic Sequence using algebra

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Not sure if my answer and my idea is right. Please help me out.

(a) Define the variable $a_n=1-\frac 1n$ , where n is a positive integer. What is the value of $a_{2020} \cdot a_{2019} \cdot a_{2018}\cdots a_2 \cdot a_1$ ?

(b) Express the following as a single fraction in lowest terms: 
$(1-1/4)\cdot (1-1/9)\cdot (1-1/16)\cdot (1-1/25)\cdots (1-1/49284)$

I already got the answer for A, which is $\frac 1 {2020}$, but I can't seem to answer B. They said it is connected somehow. Am I supposed to simplify each one? Is there an easier way to go around this problem?

Comment: Since $a_1 = 1-\frac11 = 0$, shouldn't the answer to (a) be $0$? Or is it meant to stop at $a_2$?

Comment: @Arthur In fact, stopping at $a_2$ would make more sense, since otherwise the nice trick would not be needed.

Comment: If you have enough reputation, I suggest to accept Atticus's answer. It uses exactly the idea that is supposed to be used in exercise B. Moreover, clarify Arthur's comment concerning exercise A.

Comment: i stopped at sub2 instead

Answer (score 2):

Hint for B : Show by induction $$\prod_{j=2}^n \frac{j^2-1}{j^2}=\frac{n+1}{2n}$$ for integer $n\ge 2$

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$1-\frac{1}{n^2}=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Therefore:

$$\prod_{i=2}^{222} \left(1-\frac{1}{i^2}\right)=\prod_{i=2}^{222}\left(1-\frac{1}{i}\right)\cdot \prod_{i=2}^{222}\left(1+\frac{1}{i}\right)$$

As you noticed:

$$\prod_{i=2}^{222}\left(1-\frac{1}{i}\right)=\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)\cdot \ldots\cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{222}\right)=\frac{1}{222}$$

and also

$$\prod_{i=2}^{222}\left(1+\frac{1}{i}\right)=\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{3}\right)\cdot \ldots\cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{222}\right)=\frac{\require{cancel}\cancel{3}}{2}\cdot \frac{\require{cancel}\cancel{4}}{\require{cancel}\cancel{3}}\cdot \ldots \cdot \frac{223}{\require{cancel}\cancel{222}}=\frac{223}{2}$$

Thus, the product equals:

$$\frac{1}{222}\cdot \frac{223}{2}=\frac{223}{444}$$

Comment: Wow, I admit , more elegant than my formula that must moreover first be guessed (+1)

Comment: That the fraction is in lowest terms follows by the way easily from $\gcd(223,222)=1$

Comment: @Peter, Yes, also 223 is prime.

Comment: An additional bonus, but as said we do not need it here.

Comment: sorry, just to clarify,  should i plug in the last number which is 49284 in the formula instead of 222?

Comment: @MargaretVillanueva, No. $49284=222^2$. So $$\prod_{i=2}^{222} \left(1-\frac{1}{i^2}\right)=\left(1-\frac{1}{2^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3^2}\right)\cdot \ldots\cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{222^2}\right)=\left(1-\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{9}\right)\cdot \ldots\cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{49284}\right) $$ is already the requested product.